# Crystal marking

Tags: crystal

Please help me to find out the value of a crystal[image]

Comment: Have you tried powering the circuit and measuring it? If not, why not?

Comment: I tried the same but it didn't give me any result. Whenever do this, the micro-controller stop working.

Comment: Did you search that part number on the web? It maybe 40MHZ but not certain, and the other part numbers mean a lot.

Comment: I tried also google the marked on the device but didn't get anything

Comment: You'll note that I edited your question, the article in question is _not_ a crystal oscillator, it is a crystal used _in_ an oscillator.

Answer (score 15):

This is an [Abracon](http://www.abracon.com/) crystal. Code is as follows:

```
                                      ATUHZYR
A = Abracon identifier ---------------'||||||
T = First "ten" digit of frequency ----'|||||
U = First "unit" digit of frequency ----'||||
H = First "tenth" digit of frequency ----'|||
Z = Month letter (A to L) ----------------'||
Y = Last digit of year --------------------'|
R = Traceability code ( character A to Z ) -'
```

Example:

4.0000MHz February 2003 would be coded **A040B3C** (as in your picture).

Source: Abracon.

Comment: So you mean that the crystal shown in the picture is a value of 4 MHz? Please clarify clearly is it 4 MHz or 40 MHz?

Comment: @MahbubulHossain what part of "4.0000MHz" is NOT clear?

Comment: The SE way of thanking for the answer is to accept it.